# The parameters 'filename' is missing or invalid:java2wsdl using axistools

Tags: maven, axis

axistools is not able to create the file and throwing error parameter namefile is missing or invalid. is my configuration is wrong ? I searched on internet but can't find the exact configuration. can anyone suggest me a working configuration?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java2wsdl</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <useEmitter>true</useEmitter>
                <classesDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/axistools/java2wsdl/webapp/wsdl</outputDirectory>
                 <fileName>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/axistools/java2wsdl/webapp/wsdl/WebService.wsdl</fileName>
                <location>http://xxx:xxxx/xxx/WebService</location>
                <namespace>urn:xxxx</namespace>
                <useinheritedmethods>true</useinheritedmethod>
                <style>WRAPPED</style>  
            </configuration>
        </execution>  
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fileName` in your configuration, while the correct configuration element is [`filename`](http://www.mojohaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/java2wsdl-mojo.html).

Configuration entries are case-sensitive, so your camel case configuration didn't match the expected lower case one.

Note that in this case the error message was quite helpful, indeed it was looking for `filename` and couldn't find it.

---

However, what is really misleading for this plugin, is that the [user property](http://www.mojohaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/java2wsdl-mojo.html#filename) is `fileName`. I would argue tha the matching should be reviewed and also that user properties should be prefixed with some plugin-related name in order to avoid clashes with other plugins, but that's a more generic consideration on the plugin itself, regardless of your issue.

Comment: I changed the fileName to filename, it started executing but I am getting this error.  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:axistools-maven-plugin:1.4:java2wsdl (default) on project GatewayAgentWebServicewsdl: Error executing creating WSDL from the Java code. Java2WSDL execution failed: Java2WSDL had a problem, it returned a failure status -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:axistools-maven-plugin:1.4:java2wsdl (default) on project GatewayAgentWebServicewsdl: Error executing creating WSDL from the Java code.

Comment: @RabindraChhanchan difficult to guess from the error below, I would suggest to create another question for that and provide more details running maven with the -X option

Comment: when I run the command : mvn axistools:java2wsdl                                                                The parameters 'filename' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:axistools-maven-plugin:1.4:java2wsdl are missing or invalid -> [Help 1], even though i have use small case letters.                                                                                       but it is creating the folder when I run the command : mvn process-classes                                                                                                                    but unable to generate wsdl file.